# Why is splicing an entire list or a range linear for std::forward_list?

Tags: c++, list, c++11, forward-list

Splicing a range from one list to another can be accomplished in constant time, at the expense of making `size()`'s complexity linear.

C++11 has changed that in case of `std::list` by requiring `size()` to be constant time. This broke, for example, gcc's implementation, see [[C++0x] std::list::size complexity](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49561).

Apart from the range `splice()`, **is there any other reason why** `size()` **could not be made constant time in the earlier, C++03 conforming** `std::list` **implementations?**

**Why is splicing an entire list or a range linear for** `std::forward_list`**?**

See [`splice_after()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list/splice_after), cases (1) and (3). See also 23.3.4.6 forward_list operations [forwardlist.ops] in the [standard draft N3485](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft). The `std::forward_list` doesn't even implement `size()`.

I know forward_list is a singly linked list but I don't see why one couldn't do the range `splice_after()` in constant time. I am probably missing something trivial here...

---

**EDIT:** OK, It was at least partly my misunderstanding, I expected that 4 would **not** remain in the source list. Code:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <forward_list>

using namespace std;

void dump_list(const forward_list<char>& l) {
    for(char c : l)
        cout << c << ' ';
    cout << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    forward_list<char> trg = {'a','b','c'};
    forward_list<char> src = {'1','2','3','4'};

    auto first = src.begin();
    auto last  = find(src.begin(), src.end(), '4');
    cout << "first = " << *first << ", last = " << *last << "\n\n";

    trg.splice_after(trg.begin(), src, first, last);

    cout << "Target after splice:\n";
    dump_list(trg);

    cout << "Source after splice:\n";
    dump_list(src);

    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
first = 1, last = 4
Target after splice:
a 2 3 b c
Source after splice:
1 4
```

Comment: You really should consider breaking this into two questions, as you seem to be asking about c++11 std::list::size() and std::forward_list::splice_after().

Comment: @DaveS I believe it's too late to split this question, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of a forward_list, how would you make the range splice_after constant time?  In the source list, you only have the iterators.  To remove the nodes from the source forward linked list, you will need the node immediately before `last`, so you need to search the source linearly for that linked list node.  Hence, why it's linear in the distance between `first` and `last`

The version that uses the entire source list still needs to search for the node immediately before the end of the source, so that it can be modified to point to the element after the splice in the destination.  So it also requires linear time in the size of the source.

Comment: Note that `splice_after` is `(first, last)` not `[first, last)` (as the name already suggests). So you only need to search for the iterator before `last`, which is why the complexity of (3) is "linear in `std::distance(first, last)`". The actual splicing is constant time.

Comment: Hrm, you're right.  I realized the `_after` functions placed the elements immediately after the desintation iterator (compare insert_after to insert), but didn't realize that splice was `(first,last)`

Comment: @DaveS OK, your answer helped me realize my misunderstanding, thanks!

Comment: @DaveS OK, I have posted a new question, showing my problem: [How to do range splice in constant time with std::forward_list?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14170746/341970)

Answer (score 1):

The range splice is the only reason that `size` wouldn't have been constant time in previous C++ standards. In fact the Sun CC compiler chose to make `size` constant time and *all* versions of `splice` linear.

Splicing an entire forward list is linear because you have to traverse the list you're merging to be able to link it's last node back into the list you're splicing into. I can't figure out why the range splice is linear though.

EDIT: As @Xeo points out, the range-based version also requires linear time because `last` is not included in the range and it needs to search from `first`  to find the iterator *before* `last`.

Comment: See my comment on Dave's answer on why range splice is linear.

Comment: @MarkB Upvoted and thanks! Your answer pretty much illustrates what I misunderstood too. Check my update at the bottom of my question.

Comment: @MarkB OK, I have posted a new question, showing my problem: [How to do range splice in constant time with std::forward_list?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14170746/341970)

Comment: @Xeo OK, I have posted a new question, showing my problem: [How to do range splice in constant time with std::forward_list?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14170746/341970)