# How to do range splice in constant time with std::forward_list?

Tags: c++, c++11, forward-list

I want to splice the range `[first, last]`, with both endpoints inclusive. I have iterators to the element *before* `first` and to `last`. I could do it with `splice_after()` but only in linear time.

**I belive this splice can be done in constant time.** How can I do it with `std::forward_list`?

If the question is not clear, here as is an example code showing my problem:

Code on [Live Work Space](http://liveworkspace.org/code/2TYJKT%240)

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <forward_list>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

int main() {   
    forward_list<char> trg{'a','b','c'};
    forward_list<char> src{'1','2','3','4'};

    auto before_first = src.begin();
    auto last = find(src.begin(), src.end(), '4');
    cout << "before_first = " << *before_first << ", last = " << *last << "\n";

    // trg.splice(trg.begin(), src, before_first, last); // no such splice
    auto end = last;
    ++end; // Ouch! splice has to find last again although I already had it  :(
    trg.splice_after(trg.begin(), src, before_first, end);

    cout << "Target after splice:\n";
    copy(trg.begin(), trg.end(), ostream_iterator<char>(cout," "));

    cout << "\nSource after splice:\n";
    copy(src.begin(), src.end(), ostream_iterator<char>(cout," "));

    cout << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
before_first = 1, last = 4
Target after splice:
a 2 3 4 b c
Source after splice:
1
```

Comment: the gcc libstdc++ does this in constant time, but visual c++ doesn't. ([why](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee373562%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) : _If the third member function inserts N elements, and &Right != this, an object of class iterator is incremented N times_ )

Comment: @tim Where do you that gcc does this? Please give the link.

Comment: [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/libstdc++/api/a00484.html#a90ae2ddea9cebf2b29f7399683dc3e20) (sorry I forgot to give you the link)

Comment: It looks like libstdc++ is splicing the range (first, last], which is doable in O(1), but the standard specifies splicing the range (first, last), which requires O(distance(first, last)).  The committee came very close to not messing this up. ;-(.

Comment: *You* can't range-splice a `std::forward_list` in constant time, as this would require you to modify the next-pointers inside the list-nodes.

Comment: @Xeo Could you expand on that, please?

Comment: @HowardHinnant Maybe I am just too tired but I have run the example code in the question with gcc 4.7.2 and clang 3.2 and they both splice `(first, last)` as written in the standard draft N3485, hence my question.

Comment: @Ali: You can't modify the list-nodes, you can only modify your own elements inside the `forward_list`. Think about it: How would you do the actual splicing?

Comment: @Xeo There are 2 questions: (a) Given the `before_first` and `last` iterators in the example code, is it possible to do the splice in constant time (at least in theory)? I believe yes, and you also wrote it yourself in comment to [my quesion](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14158896/341970). (b) Does `std::forward_list` offer some public API to do this splice in constant time, given iterators `before_first` and `last`?

Comment: @tim Thanks. It is weird, I have run the example code in the question with gcc 4.7.2 and clang 3.2 and they both splice `(first, last)` as written in the standard draft N3485, hence my question. The link is to gcc 4.6.2.

Comment: @Ali:  As you noticed, the link went to gcc 4.6 and that's what I based my comment on.  My bet is that the gcc 4.7 range splice is O(N).  *If* the spec was to splice (first, last], *then* it could be done in O(1).  I know of no way to achieve that with the current forward_list spec/API.

Comment: 1) Yes, splicing `(first, last]` would be `O(1)`. 2) No, there is no way to do that with `forward_list` as it currently is.

Comment: @HowardHinnant Thanks. And isn't that a defect? In my opinion the current splice_after is both confusing *and* inefficient.

Comment: @Xeo Thanks. And in your opinion, is it good this way? Isn't the current `splice_after` both confusing and inefficient?

Comment: @Xeo Could post your comment as an answer so that I can upvote / accept it?

Comment: @HowardHinnant Could post your comment as an answer so that I can upvote / accept it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The specification of `forward_list` says that the range `(first, last)` should be spliced, and there is unfortunately no way to do this in O(1) time because one needs access to `last-1` to do that, and the only way to get access to `last-1` is to iterate forward from `first`.

Had the spec been to splice the range `(first, last]`, then an O(1) splice would be possible.  I know of no way to achieve this with the current `forward_list` spec.

I think it is a defect.  However I've already tried and failed to fix it:

http://wg21.link/LWG897

However issues have been reversed in the past, especially when complaints come in from non-committee members such as yourself.  The way to file a complaint is to open a new issue, referencing any old or related issues if appropriate.  The instructions for opening an issue are [here](http://cplusplus.github.com/LWG/lwg-active.html#submit_issue).

PS:  +1 on the question.