# Splicing full list in constant time

Tags: c++, list, stdlist

I am attempting to splice (concatenate) two full std::lists in constant time. From reading the documentation and other questions
([How to do range splice in constant time with std::forward_list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14170746/how-to-do-range-splice-in-constant-time-with-stdforward-list)), I have two clarification questions:

1. Is it possible to splice two std::lists in constant time and retain the full list of each?
2. My understanding is that this functionality could be achieved by creating my own list data structure - and using a function similar to the following (pseudocode):

   ```
   List joinLists(List list1, List list2) {

     list1->tail = list2->head;

     list1->tail = list2->tail;

     return list1;

   }
   ```

Is this true? If not, I would appreciate if someone can help me understand what's going on here. I feel like I'm missing something..

The code that I am working with is here:

```
 auto simple_sorter = [this, numCores](std::vector<std::vector<std::list<unsigned int>>>& buckets_small_, std::vector<std::list<unsigned int>>& buckets_large_, std::vector<bool>& finished_, unsigned int range_low, unsigned int range_high, int thread_number)
{
    //.. irrelevant

    //Combine small buckets into single large bucket per thread
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < numCores; ++i) {
        std::list<unsigned int> list1 = buckets_large_[thread_number];
        list1.splice(list1.end(), buckets_small_[i][thread_number]);

    //...
};
```

(Note: Boost/other libraries are not an option)

Comment: `splice` is a destructive operation - the lists are "physically" joined together. You can't concatenate lists non-destructively in constant time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, and `std::list::splice` works this way (has O(1) complexity)[(1)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/splice):

> No elements are copied or moved, only the internal pointers of the list nodes are re-pointed.

2. Assuming an abstract single-linked list, you would do

   ```
   list1->back->next = list2->front;
   list1->size += list2->size;
   ```

   For a double-linked list, you would also do

   ```
   list2->front->prev = list1->back;
   ```

   If you want to insert elements of `list2` after `n`th element of `list1`, you will need to find that element, and  do the same thing

   ```
   element->next = list2->front;        
   //for a double-linked list:
   list2->front->prev = element;
   ```

   In either case, no data is copied, you just swap pointers here and there.

Comment: Thats what I thought. However, the code that I have included is running in linear time. From the documentation of std::list::splice, it runs in constant time for either of these cases:
    void splice (const_iterator position, list& x);
    void splice (const_iterator position, list&& x);
Am I missing something in my code above? I am considering just building my own list to get this functionality

Comment: @qwerty3, copying lists is O(n), so I think it is this line that works slowly rather than splice: `std::list<unsigned int> list1 = buckets_large_[thread_number];`

Comment: I missed that!! Am I correct that:
list1.splice(buckets_large_[thread_number].end(), buckets_small_[i][thread_number]); will not call the copy constructor? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @qwerty3, yes, it should be fine this way

Answer (score -1):

(Below is pseudo code)

Splicing is interweaving:

`new_list = list1[0], list2[0], list1[1], list2[1], ...`

concatenating is joining two lists together:

`new_list = list1, list2`

(Below is (slightly less pseudo) code that is untested)

to splice:

```
List splice(List list1, List list2){
  List<stuff> things ;
  List<stuff> * small_list = list1.size() > list2.size() ? &list2 : &list1 ;
  List<stuff> * big_list = list1.size() > list2.size() ? &list1 : &list2 ;
  for(int i = 0 ; i < small_list->size() ; i++ ){
    things << list1[i] << list2[i] ;
  }
  for(int i = small_list->size() ; i < big_list->size()){
    things << (*big_list)[i] ;
  }
  return things ;
}
```

Pretty sure you have to define what your list is containing in the return value and arguments (or use templates for polymorphism, which are beyond me right now)

Disclaimer: I have been spoiled by ruby and forgotten if this is valid c++...

Comment: You are mistaken about what std::list::splice does.

Comment: Yes, I was when I wrote it. It's a bad name for that function.

Comment: It's the standard name for destructive insertion of elements into a linked list. I can't think of any language which refers to interleaving as "splicing".

Comment: English. This was my mistake.